# Automate SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access database that I want to transfer over to a SQL server database.  But I have a program in VBA that I still want to utilize in the SQL database.  Is there a way to automate SQL queries like VBA does in access? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Here is a snippet of my VBA code.

```
deleteVerifTable = "DELETE * FROM VerifiedFormularies"

verifiedForm = "INSERT INTO VerifiedFormularies ([CLIENT ID], [CLIENT NAME], [MARKET SEGMENT], [FORMULARY ID], [FORMULARY NAME], [FORMULARY VERSION], [APPROVAL STATE], [ARCHIVED]) " & _
"SELECT DD.[CLIENT ID], DD.[CLIENT NAME], DD.[MARKET SEGMENT], DD.[FORMULARY ID], DD.[FORMULARY NAME], DD.[FORMULARY VERSION], DD.[APPROVAL STATE], [ARCHIVED] " & _
"FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
"Where DD.[APPROVAL STATE] IN (""APPROVED AND PUBLISHED"", ""APPROVED"", ""APPROVED WITH CHANGES"", ""APPROVED WITH POSTED CHANGES"") " & _
"AND DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT Exclusions.[Client ID] FROM Exclusions)" & _
"AND DD.[ARCHIVED] NOT IN(""YES"")" & _
"AND DD.[CLIENT ID] NOT IN(SELECT Exclusions.[Client ID] FROM Exclusions)" & _
"AND YEAR(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) >= " & year & " AND MONTH(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) > 1 AND DAY(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) > 1"
```

Comment: What do you mean by Automation?

Comment: What does your vba code do?

Comment: My VBA code allows the user to input certain dates and runs SQL Queries tailored to the info they input.

Comment: Like a search query? Those aren't automatic. There is some code in your VBA that captures a user event (like a button click) and executes a query. The same applies but the query now pulls from sql server instead of access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas Access is a DBMS with an integrated Frontend (Forms,Reports), SQL-Server is a pure DBMS. You can define table valued functions like you can in Access however you have to do everything in SQL. SQL-Server is way more powerfull than Access overall. Multiuser access to begin with. However you have to make a Frontend for the users, for example .net c# WPF with Entity Framework.

With you allready an expert in Visual Basic, VB.net would also be an option.

Or use Access as Frontend and use ADO or DAO to get the data from the sql-server database. You could also connect Access via ODBC. However I don't recommend that on a large scale application.

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code in the edit. Basically it deletes all records in a previously created table and then inserts new ones based on the information provided by the user.  Would this be possible in .Net?

Comment: you can implement these statement with a little effort (SQL dialect is off by a little, pretty sure you can find references on the differences on the web) into stored procedures and hook those in using Entity Framework. (Recommended on mass update/insert/delete operations)

Comment: If you use the reports of access much id recommend using a access frontend though. Learning curve on Forms (either Winforms or WPF) should not pose much of a problem

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have already been migrated to SQL Server you need to do the following:
Delete all the tables in your Access Database (take a backup first!).

Link your SQL Server tables back into Access. They should have the same name and structure as the original tables prior to migration.

If they do not have the same name and structure, then you will have to create views and link these.

Your existing code should then hopefully work as all the objects that it expects to exist, now do.